# What happens if you read a channel to nothing?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Can you read a goroutine channel into nothing?  where does this channel read go to in this statement?

```
go func() {
  <-ctx.Done()
  logger.Errorf("canceled: %v", ctx.Err())
}()
```

Addition:

Would this code be any different than if I used the blank identifier

```
go func() {
  _ = <-ctx.Done()
  logger.Errorf("canceled: %v", ctx.Err())
}()
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do that.

It does not need to go anywhere.

Purpose of the `Done` channel usually is just to signal the done event, so the value is not relevant and can be ignored.

It is the same as when you call a function and don't assign the return values to variables.

Consider this:

```
func getInt() int {
    return 1
}

func main() {
    getInt()  // does not "go anywhere"
}
```

See this playground showing those examples:

https://play.golang.org/p/CA8P7gYpok